# Connect Grafana to Kapua's Elasticsearch

Tags: iot, grafana, kura, kapua

I have kapua (as a docker container on my pc) and kura on the raspberryPi.
I managed to connect them, to run the example publisher and to correctly receive the data on kapua.

Now I would like to view the data via graphana (docker container) by linking this to kapua's elasticsearch (container docker).

I tried to link them indicating the address of elastichsearch localhost:9200 and to enter the credentials of kapua but it continues to give error 502 bad gateway.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have deployed grafana via Docker, the localhost is not the host but the docker container unless you have configured Grafana in network_mode `host`. How is Grafana configured?

Answer (score 0):

By default Elasticsearch in Kapua has no credential.

The capability of configure them is not yet released and it has been introduced with https://github.com/eclipse/kapua/pull/2685. It will be released in Kapua 1.1.0

Have you tried without credentials?